# Unity Player Controller From OnDrag to Multiple Touches

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying my best to make a game and currently I am moving the player with my "finger" with OnMouseDrag only on the x axis. I would like to add a feature so I can collect coins with another finger while I can still move the player. Hopefully this made sense.

Here is my player script:

```
    void OnMouseDrag()
{
    if (logic.frogTapped == true)
    {
        Vector2 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(curPosition.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

I also want to collect the coins with a line renderer, which I already have

```
    public LineRenderer lr;
    public DistanceJoint2D dj;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        dj.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = (Vector2)mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            lr.SetPosition(0, mousePos);
            lr.SetPosition(1, transform.position);
            dj.connectedAnchor = mousePos;
            dj.enabled = true;
            lr.enabled = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            dj.enabled = false;
            lr.enabled = false;
        }
        if(dj.enabled)
        {
            lr.SetPosition(1, transform.position);
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you need more information. I am very new to unity.